# Why won't my computer connect to a WiFi network?

Tags: windows-xp, networking

I'm slightly puzzled by this. I'm trying to diagnose a networking problem with a Dell Inspiron 600m running Windows XP Service Pack 3. The network is a Verizon FiOS with a Actiontec MI424WR. There are both Macs and PCS on the network. For some reason the laptop in question will connect sometimes and fail to connect other times. Why would this happen?

Here's what I'm guessing, but I'm not sure if I'm correct. Even if so, how can I correct the problem?

- Could the placement of the router be causing a weak signal (with obstructions and a closed door)?
- Could other users be causing the network to become overloaded, so that the connection is dropped or not initiated?

**EDIT:**

The computer will randomly "forget" the stored password.

Comment: Can you try to reproduce it with another notebook? )

Comment: I'm connected on my Macbook just fine. There's Windows 7 machine running as well, and another MacBook Pro. It's just this one.

Comment: Could be a million things, neighbor's wifi interfering, bad router, bad network equipment on the laptop. Keep investigating, see if you can narrow down the variables and ask more specific questions about the behavior.

Comment: is there a max # of ppl allowed to join at a time?

Comment: @Moshe so there's a problem with your notebook, not with your network/router

Comment: @wizlog - No, it's a home network, and I'm able to connect. That notebook works sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the network chipset on the problematic laptop? Also, when you say it connects sometimes - is there any pattern to it, either working when its closer to the router or when it hasn't been running for a while etc.? Do you have cordless landline phones that operate on 2.4 MHz frequency nearby?

Far too many potential causes to narrow this down without a lot more info, could simply be a solder going bad, antenna issues, susceptible to nearby phone signals etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [**inSIDDer**](http://www.metageek.net/products/inssider/)?

You could see if there is high traffic on the channel in use, and maybe move to another one which is less congested.

[image: inSIDDer]